# F. Scott Fitzgerald's "Nor Does He Spin" subheading title, what does he mean by spinning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

In his book *The Beautiful and Damned* one of the subheadings of Chapter 1 is "Nor Does He Spin." There is no specific reference to the title (I think) within this section. So what did Fitzgerald mean by spinning?

[Spoiler?] This is the section in which Anthony Patch talks to his grandfather upon returning from Rome and declares his intention to write a history book. Also at the beginning there is a listing of what his servant Bounds does for him.

Comment: This sounds like a literature question, since this can’t be answered without the broader context of the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Neither does he spin" is a way of saying that Anthony Patch "does not toil", that he does not do any work.

A familiar reference to many people older than about 50, I think. It refers to a passage in the Christian Bible, Matthew chapter 6, verse 28:

> *Why are you anxious about clothing? Consider the lilies of the field,
>   how they grow. They don’t toil, **neither do they spin**.*
>
> *Wikipedia commentary*: Two verses earlier at Matthew 6:26 Jesus told his followers not to
>   worry about food, because even the birds are provided for by God. In
>   this verse Jesus presents the example of the lilies, who also do no
>   labour. Spin in this verse is a reference to spinning thread, a
>   labour-intensive but necessary part of making clothing. Spinning was
>   traditionally women's work, something made explicit in Luke's version
>   of this verse. This then is one of the few pieces of evidence that
>   Jesus' message is meant equally for women as for men.